# Matlab and pic integration

Tags: adc, matlab, pic16f877a

i' m working in an exercise of integrating between pic16f877a and Matlab GUI. Although spending much time searching, i still have not found out how to display ADC value on a GUI panel. Hope you could help me with this. Thank you so much.

Comment: what is the actual problem? ... right now, your post is like `I can't get from Paris to Berlin`

Comment: You need to break this problem down into sections and tackle each one. How can the Matlab GUI be created? How does Matlab communicate (serial connection.) How to interface serial to the PIC. How to get the PIC to transmit and receive serial data. As it stands, this question is unanswerable as it would take a book to explain everything.

Comment: I can only send one value between pic and matlab, how can i send 2 or more? Thank you.